# Anchor-Link skips too far

Tags: html, css, accessibility

At the top of a website I'm currently working on, I defined a «Skip to content»-Link with the following markup:

```
<a href="#content" id="skip-to-content">Skip to content</a>
```

I placed this link somewhere outside the viewport, using CSS `position: absolute`. As soon as somebody focusses the link (when «tabbing» trough the page), the link gets moved back to the viewport and it pushes the content below down a bit, so it gets the space it needs.

```
#skip-to-content {

    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: -999px;

}

#skip-to-content:focus {
    position: static;
    outline: 0 none;
    border: 1px solid #681;
    top: 0;
}
```

If you now click the link, my browser skips to the content correctly, but after that the link looses focus, so the content slips up again a little bit (because the link above gets moved out of the viewport again). So in the end, you need to scroll up a little bit to see the beginning of the content. It looks, as if the anchor link would skip too far.

Is there any way I can make sure, the link always skips to the content and not some pixels below?

Please don't suggest any JavaScript-Solutions, this is basic functionality that needs to work in every browser. Thanks for your help.

— André

Comment: Can you post a link to the site?

Comment: http://www.albertroesti.ch/
(When the page has loaded, press TAB once)

Comment: What browser are you having issues with? It looks alright for me in FF.

Comment: I'm using Firefox Version 3.6.16 on Ubuntu. Could this be a browser-specific bug?

Comment: Ignore that comment, I see the problem (just wasn't enough content to move down far enough).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not an elegant solution, try adding this to your CSS, it may give you an idea of how to fix it.

```
#content {
    margin-top: -60px;
    padding: 60px 1.1em 1.1em;/*add approx 1.1em in px for top padding here*/
}
```

Where 60px is the approximate added height when the skip link is visible. It's just moving the top edge of #content up a little bit. You can try different measurements to get the padding back to where it needs to be. I didn't want to suggest wrapper divs or anything, but that could work to give you the exact 1.1em top padding you originally had.

If you can figure out the exact total added height when the link is visible, use that measurement in `em`s instead of px.

Comment: The drawback of this solution is that visitors that don't use the skip link will still see the top spacing. But I think I'm going to go with this one anyways.

Comment: They shouldn't see it. The padding offsets the negative margin, you will only see if a difference if there is a background or border which I did not see in your case. You would need to fine tune this workaround, it was more to give you an idea on a way to implement a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could just not reset the position back to `static` in your `:focus` rule.

Comment: That way the skip link would be shown on top of the other elements which I don't want. Thanks for your response nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, this defeats the purpose.